# How to name each variable using melt

Tags: r, reshape2, melt

I have a matrix that I want to reform for plotting in `ggplo2` using the `melt` function from `reshape2` but cannot find a way to add custom header names.

```
#Create toy data
MyData <- matrix(rnorm(15,500), nrow = 5, ncol = 3, dimnames = list(
    c("Unknown","0-4","4-9","10-14","15-19"),c("Area1","Area2","Area3")))

Dat2 <- melt(MyData, value.name = "Count")

#Reform data using melt, define Count as value name
MyData2 <- melt(MyData, value.name = "Count")
```

This gets me what I want but then operations that follow have to refer to the `Var1` and `Var2`.

I tried naming them explicitly using `variable.name`:

```
MyData2 <- melt(MyData, value.name = "Count",
    variable.name = c("AgeGroup", "Geo"))
```

I can of course name them after the fact using `colnames()` but would like to do it using `melt`.  Is this possible?  Do I need to back up?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `varnames` argument:

```
melt(MyData, value.name = "Count", varnames=c('AgeGroup', 'Geo'))
   AgeGroup   Geo    Count
1   Unknown Area1 501.6685
2       0-4 Area1 499.2812
3       4-9 Area1 500.3892
4     10-14 Area1 498.6380
5     15-19 Area1 500.5904
6   Unknown Area2 499.4590
7       0-4 Area2 500.5464
8       4-9 Area2 500.5635
9     10-14 Area2 500.7211
10    15-19 Area2 500.8381
11  Unknown Area3 498.8154
12      0-4 Area3 499.1818
13      4-9 Area3 499.6678
14    10-14 Area3 499.3586
15    15-19 Area3 500.3962
```

Your `MyData` is a matrix (so uses `melt.array` which uses `varnames`) not a dataframe (`melt.data.frame` uses `variable.name`). `?melt.array`.

Comment: The solution above worked for renaming the variables but i am finding that the value.name does not work for naming the value.  I feel like this worked before, looking at some past code i use for constructing diagnostic plots.  The documentation only has varnames as a part of the function so is naming the value column not even possible?

Comment: The above code works for me (i.e. `value.name="Count"` names the 'value' column "Count").

Comment: Can't explain it, I used same code and got different results. It works now.  Maybe rebooting my computer helped.  Sorry for the needless question. (sign)

Comment: [Apparently](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/manipulatr/XP6MOotmY4Q/nEU1A3srpJ8J) you have to have reshape2 loaded making sure that reshape is detached?/ not loaded? Or more simply make sure to specify: `reshape2::melt(...`

Comment: @CrunchyTopping That's it!